# OneDrive API - Create path using REST API

Tags: onedrive

I'm need to create a path for uploading a file:
-> ROOT/FOLDER 1/FOLDER 2/FOLDER 3

But I trying lot of things and the only way I make it to work is to create folders in separate calls then upload my file:

pseudo code:

```
get root folder -> create folder 1
get folder 1 -> create folder 2
get folder 2 -> create folder 3
get folder 3 -> upload my file
```

Is there a way that I can create this path in one call ??

Thank you.

EDIT:

I use the old api call:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/E75C37F6358CE17D!138:/Devis/2010/Devis_DEV004.pdf:/upload.createSession?access_token=XXXXX
```

and it returns:

```
{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"Item does not exist"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single call using PUT:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/foo/bar/baz/file.txt:/content
```

You can also use the same format with the createUploadSession action as well:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/foo1/bar2/baz3/file.txt:/createUploadSession
```

This will automatically create all the necessary folders in the path if they don't already exist.

Comment: this is a larger comment but how can I pass my authentication token?   I also have an open question here with more detail:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640533/how-to-make-rest-call-to-ms-graph-onedrive-method-with-oauth2  Similar in nature though

Comment: Hi @Ryan, thank you for your reply, I don't use graph but the old api call, see below my edit