# How to make REST call to MS Graph/OneDrive method with OAuth2

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to use the OneDrive API and I have successfully registered my app through their [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application).  I can call successfully call the [Javascript FilePicker SDK to upload and download files](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v72/js-picker-overview.htm)

That demonstrates that I have my app registered properly and the proper app/client-id's.

Now I'd like to use the REST services to upload and download files but I'm not sure how to send authentication and I don't know how to make the call to the proper URL.

**My first question is**:  How can I use the token I created in the reg service to make a REST call?

**My second question is**:  What syntax should I use to upload a file?  I don't know where to put the URL to make the call.

The PUT documentation for their upload is found [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function launchSaveToOneDrive(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //Authorization: bearer {token} 
            xhttp.open("PUT", "/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content", false);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain"); 
            xhttp.send();
            var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) that can help with REST calls including uploading files to OneDrive through the MS Graph.  The library works with client side JavaScript and Node for JavaScript server apps.

Check the [Browser folder](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/master/samples/browser/index.html) under samples to see how to use the SDK in a client app. Uploading a file would look something like this (see that link for the full code):

```
    // file variable is from the contents of an input field for example 
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

    // after user selects a file from the file picker

   client
       .api('/me/drive/root/children/Book.xlsx/content')
       .put(file, (error, response) => {
           // supports callbacks and promises
        });
```